# How to perform stemming while Using Mallet for Topic Modelling

Tags: stemming, topic-modeling, mallet, lemmatization

I would like to apply stemming using porter algorithm on the corpus saved as individual files in InputDirectory for the Mallet Model. Can somebody help how it can be performed?

Answer (score 2):

Currently your best option is to apply a stemmer before you import documents. If you're ok with Java programming, an alternative would be to create a PorterStemmer Pipe class that modifies a TokenSequence.

However, if you are training a topic model on English text, stemming is almost certainly not useful. The model can usually group related words together simply by context, and stemming often produces odd-looking not-quite-words that are difficult for users to interpret.

Comment: How is it possible to apply stemming to multiple files in a folder, before importing document using python or any other tool. Please Suggest